# How to swap link for text in div with Javascript of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexof

I want to turn the following html:

```
<div id="myText">Another hurricane is coming <a data-number="23">here</a>. And check out pictures <a data-number="43">here</a>.</div>
```

into this:

```
<div id="myText">Another hurricane is coming @[23]. And check out pictures @[43].</div>
```

I'm basically trying to fetch each "data-number"-value and putting it into square brackets, whilst omitting the text in the a-tags.

Any idea on how best to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myText a[data-number]').each(function() {
    var text = '@[' + $(this).data('number') + ']';
    $(this).replaceWith(text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `.replaceWith()`

```
$('#myText').find('a').replaceWith(function(){
       return "@["+ $(this).data('number')+"]";
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2vsmdm8x/)

You could use `.find('a[data-number]')` like @ColinDeClue pointed out in the comments to be sure to get anchors with the attribute `data-number`.

Comment: Might want to add a `[data-number]` to the selector, just in case there's other anchor tags.